# Is *.xls MS Excel default format in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel, table

Is it always necessary that whenever we want to show our data kept in Excel spreadsheets in ArcMap, that it must be in `.xls`? Is `.xls` a default format for ArcMap?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question so I removed your second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ArcMap can load lots of dataformats. The direct load of xls/xlsx is pretty nice as you have all the named sections beside the tables and don´t need to transform anything. There are some guidelines (directly copied from ArcGis resources) how the tables in Excel need to look like:

- Field names need to start with a letter.
- Field names should only include alphanumeric characters or underscores.
- None of these: `~@#$%^&*()-+=|\,<>?/{}.!’[]:;
- No spaces (That includes before the field name, in the middle, or after it.
- Field names will be cut off after 64 characters
- Do not used reserved words as field names

That means usually you need to prepare your table a bit (for example the column headers safed as numbers are recognized as data by ArcMap and need to be coerced into text is a common problem). But when its done its comfortable. But that would need to be done for .csv as well (ArcMap is using the schema.ini mechanism of Windows here which makes this interesting as well).

Comment: It might be worth noting that the row limit for an xls file is 65,536 while the row limit for xlsx files is 1,048,576. Something to keep in mind when working with large tables.